# "Loop Cut and Slide in blender 2.80 beta?

Tags: customization, shortcut

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-blender-a/9780133886283/ch06lev2sec21.html

Ctrl+R command exists, I have also found this command in `Preferences`.

But where is it and its panel in the general window? It seems all the screens and tutorials are too old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this tools inside the Tool Shelf, in edit mode

[image]

Hope that helps.

Good Luck

Comment: Almost. "Loop Cut and Slide" is single tool in older versions and currently it is 2 separate tools. I have a tutorial for older versions. Could you explain how to deal with it now?

Comment: The Loop Cut Is the Loop Cut and Slide, once you make the first cut, you will  see a small menu to slide the edges. If you use CTRL + R you will have more control because you don't need the menu to slide the edges, just the mouse (i'm not sure why, sorry).
https://photos.app.goo.gl/7fRcRMcewfeKX4KZ6

Comment: That is a slightly different tool, it doesn't allow to set the number of cuts with the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the context menu **in edge select mode**:

[image]

(I think the *context* menu is a weird choice because it always works the same, no matter the context.)